# Creating a document with { strict: false } in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The task is to store some documents into MongoDB. The documents have the same top-level but from there they could be different.
The structure of the payload is:

```
{
  "types": "a", //the type can be "a", "b" or "c"
  "details" : {
       ... // the details object structure is different for each type
    }
}
```

and this is the model I wrote:

```
const Details = { strict: false };

const MyOrder = new Schema({
  types: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  },
  details: Details,
});

module.exports = Order = mongoose.model('myOrder', MyOrder);
```

I set details with `{ strict: false }` because I want to get its data no matter what structure it has. Maybe it's wrong something there.

When a POST request is done, the document saved into the database it looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("...")
types: "a"
__v : 0
```

It saved the `types` but nothing about the details.

Is it a way to save the details too?

Comment: use can use `Discriminators` in `mongoose` without turning off schema strict option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by not creating another `Details` object like above but adding `{ strict: false }` inside the Schema. Like this:

```
const MyOrder = new Schema(
  {
    types: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    },
  },
  { strict: false }
);

module.exports = Order = mongoose.model('myOrder', MyOrder);
```